# FunctionInvokeUrlNotFound when creating resource group from ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

I have a ARM template exported from my earlier created resource group. I'm trying to create my resource group based on this template. Everything gets created except LogicApp. I receive an error saying invoke url for function '' not found. error code: FunctionInvokeUrlNotFound. I cannot find even similar problem on the internet to somehow troubleshoot this.

This is the ARM template file I'm using: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlZTLK9l4tr0hjM02gWfY_JgszJz?e=n1bfYo

Comment: This is probably something with a function step in your logicApp. Besides, I think you shouldn't deploy logicApp here. This should be a part of deployment not resources creation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out there was missing some http triggering config. Adding appropriate bindings fixed the issue. Here is the config for Azure Function:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_HPlusFunctions20200819162035_name'), '/OrderFunction')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_HPlusFunctions20200819162035_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "script_root_path_href": "https://hplusfunctions20200819162035.azurewebsites.net/admin/vfs/site/wwwroot/OrderFunction/",
            "script_href": "https://hplusfunctions20200819162035.azurewebsites.net/admin/vfs/site/wwwroot/bin/HPlusFunctions.dll",
            "config_href": "https://hplusfunctions20200819162035.azurewebsites.net/admin/vfs/site/wwwroot/OrderFunction/function.json",
            "href": "https://hplusfunctions20200819162035.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/OrderFunction",
          "config": {
            "bindings": [
              {
                "name": "req",
                "webHookType": "genericJson",
                "direction": "in",
                "type": "httpTrigger"
              },
              {
                "name": "res",
                "direction": "out",
                "type": "http"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
    }
```